# How to move to next or previous ques-tion in a quiz app?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to fetch the questions from the database in meteor. I'm new to meteor.js and do not really know how to go about it.

```
Template.quiz.helpers({
    //add you helpers here
    'questionList': function () {
       return Questions.find({},{limit: 1}).fetch();
    }
});

Template.quiz.events({
    'click .next': function (evt) {
         evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**db**

```
{
  "_id": "kAKbfLRHFZinrrRZv",
  "selected_subject": "English",
  "question": "ekek",
  "ans_A": "e",
  "ans_B": "q",
  "ans_C": "t",
  "ans_D": "o",
  "correctAns": "e"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this -

Set a session variable `questionNumber` when your quiz template is rendered. You will be using the value of this session variable to move from one question to another using the skip option in your `Questions.find()` statement. Depending on whether a user clicks on the next or previous button, increment or decrement the value stored in this session variable respectively.

```
Template.quiz.onRendered(function () {
  Session.setDefault("questionNumber", 0);
});

Template.quiz.helpers({
  'questionList': function () {
    return Questions.find({}, { skip: Session.get("questionNumber"), limit: 1 });
  }
});

Template.quiz.events({
  'click .next': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Session.set("questionNumber", Session.get("questionNumber") + 1);
  },
  'click .previous': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Session.set("questionNumber", Session.get("questionNumber") - 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: I like this idea alot actually. It would be even better if you had the questions numbered in the proper order on the DB.

Comment: Could you please provide an example for your suggestion as I don't quite understand it?

Comment: The example he provided should really be all you need.

The helpers are reactive, so when the value of the questionNumber `Session` variable changes, the question rendered in the template will automatically change as well.

Since you are storing a number as the questionNumber variable, and then adding +1 to it every time the user clicks next, it changes the `skip` parameter of the Minimongo query, and therefore returns the next question.

You'll just need to make sure that the Questions collection is sorted in the order that you want them to appear.

Comment: That's right. I have left the implementation details of the sort order to the OP as he best knows the order of questions.

Comment: i do not have a 'questionNumber' field in my db, i want it to autoincrement as i add questions to the db.

Comment: `questionNumber` is a session variable in the above solution and not a field in your collection. The value in this variable will be incremented or decremented depending on whether the next or previous button is clicked. The value effectively tells how many questions to skip in your query.